# Manhwa/manga about a guy who seeks revenge for his family

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am not 100% sure but I would say it was a fully colored manhwa.

There are special abilities or powers.

The MC's daughter and wife are killed by some kind of mafia and he gathers a team to get revenge.
He also trains his legs, which he can transform as his power, and even goes through some kind of surgery to get stronger.

Someone on his team could go through walls, and I recall there being some kind of sniper as well.

I am pretty sure he had the nickname of "Vagabond" or something of the likes because of his looks.

Comment: Hi @Abel, I want to ask something to clarify. Does the man got updated version of his legs(his legs wrapped by tree's root to do so) by someone else? The group he gather try to rob a bank(actually a secret base of organization)? Does there also have a boy got adopted but actually had super power and go to a training camp? The girl in the adopted house love him and wish to have super power and then also go to the training camp? The story you remember match mine well except for the fully colored since part 1 is 60% color 40%not. part 2 yes.

Comment: Hi @someoneuseless I do recall the tree's roots and them robbing a bank. I also remember that much, much later they end up fighting some kind of god who comes to destroy their planet. Do you know the name of the story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the comment is right then this is [Trace](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=48965).

The story set in the contemporary South Korea. Some 30 years ago, unidentified creatures appeared out of nowhere and have attacked people. They have caused massive destruction wherever they go. The monsters are called "Trouble", and get the world have fallen into chaos. Along with the first appearance of the "Troubles", some number of humans were born with or acquired supernatural abilities. These mutants called "Trace" are the only ones who can fight off the "Trouble". The "Trace" are also considered freaks and generally shunned by the community because some of them misused the powers for their own interest.

The plot revolves around two main characters. Sah Gang-kwon, a high school student born as a "Trace" who attempts to hide his ability. The other is Kim Yun-Seong, who acquired his "Trace" abilities during his early 30s. Soon after the acquision, his wife and daughter were taken away from him for experimental purposes.

Kim Yun-seong is the MC you remembered.